# Calculate date difference from previous row of each unique cRt in MySQL

Tags: mysql, datediff

I have a table with column `cDate`.

I want to calculate the time difference between two consecutive record with the same `cRt` value.

E.g.:

```
+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------+
| cNode         | cEl      | cDate               | cEvent                      | cRt      |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------+
| SD20-2-100102 | SD100102 | 2020-04-13 11:34:35 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD100102 |
| SD20-2-100102 | SD100102 | 2020-04-13 07:15:14 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD100102 |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------+
```

The time difference for `SD100102 cRt` is 259.

```
mysql> 
SELECT
    ROUND(
        time_to_sec(
            (
                TIMEDIFF(
                    '2020-04-13 11:34:35',
                    '2020-04-13 07:15:14'
                )
            )
        ) / 60
    ) AS td;
+-----+
| td  |
+-----+
| 259 |
+-----+
1 row in set
```

Table:

```
+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------+
| cNode         | cEl      | cDate               | cEvent                      | cRt      |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------+
| SD20-2-100102 | SD100102 | 2020-04-13 11:34:35 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD100102 |
| SD20-2-100102 | SD100102 | 2020-04-13 07:15:14 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD100102 |
| SD40-2-103423 | SD103423 | 2020-04-06 06:21:50 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103423 |
| SD40-2-103423 | SD103423 | 2020-04-06 06:20:21 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103423 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-23 15:19:37 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-23 15:17:53 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-21 14:29:50 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-21 14:19:50 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-02-13 07:33:00 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-02-13 07:31:55 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-01-13 15:57:16 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-01-12 00:10:50 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103484 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-04-07 12:20:48 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-04-07 11:59:47 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-03-05 11:46:03 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-03-05 09:13:46 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-18 12:30:21 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-18 12:29:12 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-14 07:52:28 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-14 07:50:42 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN  | SD103565 |
+---------------+----------+---------------------+-----------------------------+----------+
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no performant way to do this without window functions in MySql versions prior to 8.0.
One way is for every row to get the max cDate before the current cDate for the same cRt:

```
SELECT t.*,
  ROUND(time_to_sec((TIMEDIFF(
    t.cDate,
    (SELECT MAX(cDate) FROM tablename WHERE cRt = t.cRt AND cDate < t.cDate)
  ))) / 60) AS td
FROM tablename t
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubYu9adEFcoKjnZwN6vdYv/1).
If you can use `LAG()` window function:

```
SELECT *,
  ROUND(time_to_sec((TIMEDIFF(
    cDate,
    LAG(cDate) OVER (PARTITION BY cRt ORDER BY cDate)
  ))) / 60) AS td
FROM tablename
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ubYu9adEFcoKjnZwN6vdYv/2).

Results:

```
| cNode         | cEl      | cDate               | cEvent                     | cRt      | td    |
| ------------- | -------- | ------------------- | -------------------------- | -------- | ----- |
| SD20-2-100102 | SD100102 | 2020-04-13 11:34:35 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD100102 | 259   |
| SD20-2-100102 | SD100102 | 2020-04-13 07:15:14 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD100102 |       |
| SD40-2-103423 | SD103423 | 2020-04-06 06:21:50 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103423 | 1     |
| SD40-2-103423 | SD103423 | 2020-04-06 06:20:21 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103423 |       |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-23 15:19:37 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 2     |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-23 15:17:53 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 2928  |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-21 14:29:50 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 10    |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-04-21 14:19:50 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 50340 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-02-13 07:33:00 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 1     |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-02-13 07:31:55 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 44135 |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-01-13 15:57:16 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 | 2386  |
| SD20-2-103484 | SD103484 | 2020-01-12 00:10:50 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103484 |       |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-04-07 12:20:48 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 21    |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-04-07 11:59:47 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 47534 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-03-05 11:46:03 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 152   |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-03-05 09:13:46 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 22843 |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-18 12:30:21 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 1     |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-18 12:29:12 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 6037  |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-14 07:52:28 | POSITIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 | 2     |
| SD40-2-103565 | SD103565 | 2020-02-14 07:50:42 | NEGATIVE REMOTE CONTROL SN | SD103565 |       |
```